# "In order for" vs. "for"

Tags: grammar, readability

Sometimes when writing I instinctively use "in order for" instead of "for" under the impression that this will make the sentence more readable, even though "for" would have been equally grammatical. For example:

> As Quine said, there is a potentially infinite number of things that must
>   be true in order for that statement to be considered true.

Am I correct in assuming that it is better to use "in order for" instead of just "for" in this situation? Or am I wrong and it's actually *worse* to use "in order for" here? Or perhaps it doesn't matter at all and both options are equally good? I am not a native English speaker and a professor of mine who also isn't just corrected this sentence removing the "in order for" and leaving only "for", but I was not convinced that it's better with only "for". I'm curious about what native speakers or language specialists would have to say.

Comment: At least in the context you suggest and in a few others I can think of, they both sound equally fine to me.

Comment: It avoids a level of garden-pathiness by blocking other usages of 'for'. << As Quine said, there is a potentially infinite number of things that must be true for each referent, descriptor, relationship, transformation _and wider context_ involved in order for a statement to be validly considered true. >>

Comment: @KannE the "in order for" in the example from the M-W dictionary ("They were told that [in order] for them to keep their jobs, they would have to accept a cut in pay.") could be replaced by just "for", so it doesn't help me much. It doesn't tell me anything about one being more recommended compared to the other..

Comment: @Ariel  "In order for" is not a constituent. "In order" is a compound preposition phrase and "for that statement to be considered true" is an infinitival clause functioning as its complement. "For" is not omissible.

Comment: @Ariel "For" doesn't replace "in order". It's part of the infinitival clause "for that statement to be considered true". "In order" is optional, but "for" is obligatory. As you've been told, the PP "in order" is optional in your example -- there is no difference in meaning, so what is your problem?

Comment: Dictionaries are misleading when they say that "in order for" is an idiom. We know that "for" is not part of an idiom "in order for" simply because "in order" is omissible without loss of grammaticality, providing of course that the infinitival clause contains a subject.  And we can also say "He walked to work in order to save money", where the infinitival does not contain a subject and thus "for" is not required. Note that the subordinator "for" is only used with _to_-infinitival clauses that contain a subject.

Comment: To help, I'll add that I use *for* alone when X connects directly with Y. With intermediary steps between X and Y, I'll use *in order for* (for the order of things). Same with *to* and *in order to* (which I rarely use).

Answer (score 0):

> *As Quine said, there is a potentially infinite number of things that*
>   *must be true* (*in order*) *for that statement to be considered true*.

The simple answer is that the PP "in order" is semantically optional. Personally, I can't see any real stylistic preference one way or the other, though some speakers may consider its inclusion to be slightly more formal.

Syntactically, the subordinate infinitival clause can function as purpose adjunct itself, rather than be governed by the PP, so that's not a deciding factor either.

Note that, despite what some dictionaries say, "in order for" is not a constituent. "In order" is a preposition phrase and "for" is a subordinator introducing the *to*-infinitival clause *for that statement to be considered* *true*, which is a separate constituent. The infinitival clause functions as complement of the prep "in order" or, if the latter is not present, as direct complement of "true".

Note also that the clause subordinator "for" only occurs with *to*-infinitival clauses that contain a subject, as your example does.

Answer (score 0):

If we concede that "In order for" and "In order to" are analogous, then some reference writers are not so charitable:

In "The Careful Writer" by Theodore M. Bernstein under "In Order To":

"A wasteful locution. In the vast majority of instances *in order* may be deleted with no loss."

Comment: Why would you group the words "in order for", and "in order to" together when neither of them are constituents? In any case, clauses introduced with "for" have a different structure to those introduced by "to".